# Force new subscription or uninstall in Chrome Web Store extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a published and used Chrome extension that I want to monetize. I've added a small monthly subscription ($0.99) for use of the extension and maintain it frequently.

I introduced the subscription after some of the users installed the extension, none of which are subscribed but still use the application as if they were.

Is there a way to prompt the user for a subscription if they already have the extension installed? Or do I accept that they won't have to pay and cut my losses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this comes from [One-Time Payment page in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#free2paid), I think it's generally a good advice:

> ## Migrating from a free to a paid experience
>
> If you decide to migrate from a free experience to a paid experience, you should consider what experience you want to provide for any user who installed your item prior to the change. We strongly recommend grandfathering these users into the full, paid experience though the decision is yours.

From a technical standpoint, prior users *do* have a license issued authomatically:

> Users who installed your item prior to the change will have a `FREE_TRIAL` license. To determine if a user installed your item prior to the price change, you can check the createdTime value in the license to determine when they first installed it.

Are you checking the `license.accessLevel` in the extension? If you don't, your license code may think they are fully licensed.

But suppose that you do want to charge users (subscription implies ongoing costs), then the usual dilemma applies.

1. Users that are not grandfathered in are likely to complain if you degrade their experience. You have to be careful with the announcement.
2. If you don't have any logic offloaded to a server, anyone can go in and rip your license code out. That is a fight likely not worth fighting.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they have that `.crx` file (*older version*) in their computer and your extension's functionality and features are not **server side**, you cannot do anything about it.

You can however note at the change log or through your extension that the *subscription* helps you with the development and maybe some of the users will be kind enough to support you.